# attach a log function to be run on all functions in a class

Tags: javascript, node.js

Assuming I have this javascript class that I use in nodejs:

```
modules.export = class Core{
     constructor(app) {}
     func1(){}
     func2(){}
}
```

I call it like this:

```
const Core  = require(/*path to core file*/)
core = new Core()
```

How can I attach a function to be called every time the `func1()` or `func2()` or the contructor is called?

i.e call a log function every time the two functions are called. Eventually, this would make an easier site wide logging in case the app ever got too large.

Comment: You can use [Zone for NodeJS](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/zones-for-nodejs-apis-670281ac5aa5)

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from Parent Class which will be responsible for binding with log  and overwrite Derived class functions as below

```js
class BaseLog {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Constructor called');
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.__proto__).forEach(key=> {
      const fun = this.__proto__[key];
      // Can not overwrite constructors           
      if (typeof fun === 'function' && key!=='constructor') {
        const newFunc = function newFunc() {
          console.log('called', key);
          return fun.apply(this, arguments);
        };
        this.__proto__[key] = newFunc
      }
    })
  }
}

class Test extends BaseLog {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.a = 10;
  }

  getA() {
    return this.a
  }
}
test = new Test()
console.log(test.getA())
```